# Draw the complex exponential signal?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to draw the complex exponential signal with the label, angle like that. Could anyone tell me how, or supply me with some reference? Would be perfect. Thanks a lot.

```
\documentclass\[border=5mm\]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw \[magenta, thick\] circle \[radius=3\];
\draw \[blue\] circle \[radius=4.3\];

\draw \[Circle-\] (0,0) -- node\[left,red\] {$R$} (60:3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run with `xelatex` or `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` if you want the animation with `multido`:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot,multido}

\begin{document}
\def\i{300}
%\multido{\i=360+-6}{60}{%
\begin{pspicture}(-1.3,-1.3)(3.5,1.5)
\psaxes[labels=none,linewidth=0.5pt,linecolor=black!20]{->}%
   (0,0)(-1.2,-1.2)(1.2,1.2)[Re,0][Im,90]
\pscircle[linestyle=dashed,linewidth=0.4pt]{1}
\pnode(1;\i){R}
{\psset{linecolor=gray,linestyle=dashed,
    linewidth=0.5\pslinewidth,dash=2pt 2pt}
 \psline(0,0|R)(R)
 \psline(R)(R|0,0)}
\psset{arrows=->}\fboxsep=0pt
 \psline[linewidth=1.2pt](R)\rput(1.1;\i){\footnotesize A}
 \psline[linecolor=red](0,0|R)
 \psline[linecolor=blue](R|0,0)
 \rput[l](0.25,1.1){\footnotesize Circle of magnitude A}
 \psarcn{->}(0,0){0.4}{0}{\i}\rput[lb](0.45;\i){$\scriptstyle-\Omega_0t$}
\end{pspicture}%
%}

\end{document}
```

[image]

and the same as animation:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I hope I interpret your question correctly. You want to draw axes, an angle and annotations. IMHO the tutorial of the pgfmanual is a great place to learn these things.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,angles,quotes,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\draw [magenta, thick] circle [radius=3];
\draw [blue] circle [radius=4.3];

\draw [Circle-] (0,0) -- node[left,red] {$R$} (60:3) coordinate (R);
% axes
\draw[latex-latex] (0,5) node[above]{Im} -- (0,0) coordinate (O) 
-- (5,0) coordinate(X) node[right]{Re};
% angle
\draw pic ["$\Omega_0t$",angle eccentricity=1.33,draw,-latex,angle radius=1cm,fill=blue!50] 
{angle = X--O--R};
\path (60:4.3) coordinate (C) node[above right=5mm,inner sep=0pt] (C'){Circle of magnitude $A$};
\draw[-latex] (C'.south west) to[out=-90,in=60] (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]